# Redmine plugin activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm developing a Redmine plugin, and I want to add a custom field programmatically when I'm activating my plugin, but i don't find the plugin activation method in the core Redmine, which I want to wrap.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not really sure what you are looking for as a Redmine plugin is something that you don't really activate as Redmine user at runtime.

Your plugin is 'active' and will be loaded on Redmine start when it resides in the plugins folder.
The first executed code is in the init.rb of your plugin.

Also you should clarify what you mean by "add a custom field":

- create a new custom field
- add a custom field to a tracker and/or project
- create a new custom field **type**

Maybe you should elaborate more in detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Just came to my mind:

If by '**plugin**' you mean '**project module**' (which is in fact something you can (de-)activate) then you probably should patch the project class and add an after_save hook where you check if your project module is active and program your actions accordingly...